# Override item layout of credit memo in email template and add new column

Tags: magento2, email-templates, creditmemo

I want to override the item layout in credit memo email template and want to add new column in that. I tried to override that but that item layout in email template is not showing.

> Overridden email path:-
> app/design/frontend/<company_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Sales/email/creditmemo_new.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Credit memo for your %store_name order" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var comment":"Credit Memo Comment",
"var creditmemo.increment_id":"Credit Memo Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_creditmemo_items\" creditmemo=$creditmemo order=$order":"Credit Memo Items Grid",
"var this.getUrl($store, 'customer/account/')":"Customer Account URL",
"var order.getCustomerName()":"Customer Name",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"var order.shipping_description":"Shipping Description"
} @-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>.' store_email=$store_email |raw}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans "Your Credit Memo #%creditmemo_id for Order #%order_id" creditmemo_id=$creditmemo.increment_id order_id=$order.increment_id}}</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend comment}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var comment|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_creditmemo_items" creditmemo=$creditmemo order=$order}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: Please try to override this template from Admin. Go to Marketing > Email Templates and add a new one. You can add a new column over there.

Comment: In email template, only layout handler is called, we cannot add the column in item rederer, it is called through layout sales_email_order_creditmemo_items and in default.phtml file. But somehow that layout is not called in the email.

Comment: What column and values do you want to add, LMK? I will create a small extension at my localhost then share the code with you!

Comment: Add any custom product attribute in the column or you can take default product atrribute as well like sku or qty available

Comment: You want to add a new column in this table right? https://tinyurl.com/2qfdj73f
Can I add the here SKU?
Let me know if I am on right track.

Comment: yes, you can add SKU in the column

Comment: Where do you want to add a custom column in Email or in the backend admin?

Comment: @RonakRathod, In the email template

Comment: Okay, so you want to add sku column in the credit memo email Right?

Comment: @Mitul Vadalia just added code. This will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding new coloumn in credit memo email. You can do the following things. Just override 2 templates in your custom theme. VERY SIMPLE

I just tried on our local instace it is working as expected.

1. Copy form vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/creditmemo/default.phtml to app/design/frontend/Mytheme/navneet/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/creditmemo/default.phtml

   ```
        <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    ?>
    <?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
    <?php $_order = $block->getItem()->getOrder(); ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="item-info<?= ($block->getItemOptions() ? ' has-extra' : '') ?>">
            <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
            <p class="sku"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
            <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()) : ?>
                <dl>
                    <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option) : ?>
                        <dt><strong><em><?= $block->escapeHtml($option['label']) ?></em></strong></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */  nl2br($block->escapeHtml($option['value'])) ?>
                        </dd>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
            <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
                <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item->getOrderItem())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
        </td>
        <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
        <td class="item-qty"><?= (float) $_item->getQty() ?></td>
        <td class="item-price">
            <?= /* @noEscape */  $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
   ```
2. Copy form vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/creditmemo/items.phtml to app/design/frontend/Mytheme/navneet/Magento_Sales/templates/email/creditmemo/items.phtml

   ```
            <?php
        /**
         * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
         * See COPYING.txt for license details.
         */

        ?>
        <?php $_creditmemo = $block->getCreditmemo() ?>
        <?php $_order      = $block->getOrder() ?>
        <?php if ($_creditmemo && $_order) : ?>
            <table class="email-items">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="item-info">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Items')) ?>
                        </th>
                        <th class="item-info">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>
                        </th>
                        <th class="item-qty">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>
                        </th>
                        <th class="item-subtotal">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php foreach ($_creditmemo->getAllItems() as $_item) : ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) : ?>
                        <tbody>
                            <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                        </tbody>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <tfoot class="order-totals">
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('creditmemo_totals') ?>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
   ```

Here is the screenshot at my local instance credit memo email template:

New Column SKU added:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You need to override this file vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/creditmemo/items.phtml in your theme app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/email/creditmemo/items.phtml**

Update a code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

?>
<?php $_creditmemo = $block->getCreditmemo() ?>
<?php $_order      = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_creditmemo && $_order) : ?>
    <table class="email-items">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Items')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-qty">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-subtotal">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($_creditmemo->getAllItems() as $_item) : ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) : ?>
                <tbody>
                    <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                </tbody>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tfoot class="order-totals">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('creditmemo_totals') ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

?>
<?php $_creditmemo = $block->getCreditmemo() ?>
<?php $_order      = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_creditmemo && $_order) : ?>
    <table class="email-items">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="item-sku" style="width: 90px; padding: 15px 0;border-top:1px solid 
                #d1d1d1;color: #000;text-align:left; ">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sku')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Items')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-qty">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-subtotal">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($_creditmemo->getAllItems() as $_item) : ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) : ?>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="sku" style="border-top:1px solid #d1d1d1;vertical-align: middle;padding: 10px 10px;">
                            <p class="sku"><?= 'testqygyt'.$block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                </tbody>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tfoot class="order-totals">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('creditmemo_totals') ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```